# Can't trigger class function after nesting object (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, methods, nested, user-defined-functions

I created a class called item. This class returns its variables with the function itemdata();
I'm creating object instances of this class and adding them to another object through this:

```
//Item Creation

function additem(Name:String,file:Class,workswith:String,tu rnsinto:String,examine:String,X:Number,Y:Number) {
var itemname:item = new item();
var ItemDB:Array= new Array();
itemname.create(Name,file,workswith,turnsinto,exam ine,X,Y);
itemname.addChild(itemname.itemdata("filename")); 
ItemDB.push(itemname);
var itemindb:int = ItemDB.length-1;
Items.addChild(ItemDB[itemindb]);
}

//--
```

However when trying to access the item's variables after it's clicked (in the following way:)

```
stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK,InventoryPickup);
function InventoryPickup(event:MouseEvent):void {
var t:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
if (t.parent==Items){
t.itemdata();
}
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method itemdata through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you defined var t as `DisplayObject` and now it has not method itemdata because it is not instance of `Item` class...
Try this:

```
var t:Item = Item(event.target);
```

instead of:

```
var t:DisplayObject = DisplayObject(event.target);
```